# Crash validating related model created using inline admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm creating a one-to-one model to extend the functionality of an existing model type, but I want it to only allow creating the extension model in certain cases. I enforce this constraint by throwing a `ValidationError` in the `full_clean` on the new `Extended` model. This works great when I create Extended models using Extended's `ModelAdmin` directly (it highlights the `a` field if it's the wrong type), but when I use `StackedInline` to inline `Extended` creation in `A`s ModelAdmin, and `A` is the wrong type, the form fails to catch the `ValidationError` and I get the message `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`

This is how I have the models set up:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(...)

class Extended(models.Model)
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)

    def clean_fields(self, **kwargs):
        if self.a.type != 3:
            raise ValidationError({'a': ["a must be of type 3"]})
        super(Extended, self).clean_fields(**kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Extended, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class ExtendedInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Extended

@admin.register(A)
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ExtendedInline,)
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 618, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1521, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 34, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 30, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 145, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1470, in changeform_view
    self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1104, in save_related
    self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1092, in save_formset
    formset.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 636, in save
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 767, in save_new_objects
    self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 900, in save_new
    obj.save()
  File "/code/app/models.py", line 162, in save
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1171, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'a': [u'a must be of type 3']}
```

I'm currently using Django version 1.8

Comment: You shouldn't override `clean_fields` like that -- it will prevent the regular field validation. That code belongs in the `clean()` method. However I don't think that's going to fix your problem.

Comment: @Alasdair I also call `super(...).clean_fields` but I didn't include it in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change

```
raise ValidationError({'a': ["a must be of type 3"]})
```

to

```
raise ValidationError(["a must be of type 3"])
```

I don't get the crash and it appears on the inline admin.

Answer (score 1):

Inline foreignkeys are excluded on the calls to full_clean() that happen in modelform validators, so your ValidationError is not being caught by the form's is_valid() call.

From django/forms/models.py:

```
def _post_clean(self):
    opts = self._meta

    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()

    try:
        self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, exclude)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)

    # Foreign Keys being used to represent inline relationships
    # are excluded from basic field value validation. This is for two
    # reasons: firstly, the value may not be supplied (#12507; the
    # case of providing new values to the admin); secondly the
    # object being referred to may not yet fully exist (#12749).
    # However, these fields *must* be included in uniqueness checks,
    # so this can't be part of _get_validation_exclusions().
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        if isinstance(field, InlineForeignKeyField):
            exclude.append(name)

    try:
        self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)

    # Validate uniqueness if needed.
    if self._validate_unique:
        self.validate_unique()
```

They're being caught in save() instead (where you call full_clean without the exclusion), which is too late.

Move your validation to clean() instead:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.a.type != 3:
        raise ValidationError({'a': ["a must be of type 3"]})
```

Then there will be no need to call full_clean from your save method. This method is where any validation of this sort should go [as per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this in the a regular (non-inline) `ModelAdmin`, but this solution should also work.

I simply wrapped the [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) in a try except and sent the exception message through a [`messages.warning()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message)

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages

class ConstraintErrorBoundaryMixin:
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        try:
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        except Exception as exc:
            messages.error(request, str(exc))
```